# How to make an svg text with d3.js that flashes from black to white an back continuously?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The code below does not work as intended. I would like to create a text svg that alternates continuously between black and white. Help appreciated!

```
   <svg width="1000" height="500">
            <text x="100" y="400" fill="red" id="test123">Make this Text    Blink!</text>
       </svg>
       <script type="text/javascript">

           function text_blink(){
               d3.select("#test123")
                 .transition()
                 .duration(1000)
                 .style("fill", "rgb(255,255,255)")
                 .transition()
                 .duration(1000)
                 .style("fill", "rgb(0,0,0)");
             }

           for (x=0; x<40; x++){      
               text_blink()

           }
           </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [transition.on](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_on), which...

> Adds or removes a listener to each selected element for the specified event typenames

... you can call the same function repeatedly when the transition ends:

```js
function blink() {
  d3.select("text").transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("fill", "rgb(255,255,255)")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("fill", "rgb(0,0,0)")
    .on("end", blink)
    //    ^------^---- calling blink again when the transition ends
}

blink();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <text x="100" y="40" fill="red" id="test123">Make this Text Blink!</text>
</svg>
```

PS: On an explanatory note, be aware that, in JavaScript, when you do this...

```
for (x=0; x<40; x++){      
    text_blink()
}
```

... you are simply calling `text_blink()` 40 times in just a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: indeed, I got that, but the question remains,  how could i implement it in order to have it execute continuously?

Comment: And thanks for solution! i did not look at your complete post, initially...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"on"` you can use `.each` in d3 version 3.

```
function blink() {
  d3.select("text").transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("fill", "rgb(255,255,255)")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("fill", "rgb(0,0,0)")
    .each("end", blink)
    //    ^------^---- calling blink again when the transition ends
}

blink();
```